# TypeError in python CoLab

Tags: python, compiler-errors, typeerror

I used the Collab website to program in Python and I got this error and I don't know how to correct it. I was trying to apply a code to some dataset, but I encountered this error. Here is a picture of the code and another picture of the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xYVH.png)

Comment: Please post code instead of an image. And make sure it can be reproduced correctly, so we are able to fix the issue.

Comment: You can add a link to a Colab Notebook

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1M3DBgTWUIA0j0X2YhkzEGQwP4piTP6Ut?userstoinvite=12993973%40uofn.edu.om&actionButton=1#scrollTo=jHn-qTX0L3Gj

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to see your code to try to exact reproduce your situation.

But if we talking about *labelcolor* and *facecolor* this is the small example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Set the figure size
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 3.50]
# plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

# Create a figure and set of subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel('$number$ of clients')

# Get the data
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tokern/piicatcher/master/tests/samples/sample-data.csv')
df.groupby(['state'])['city'].count().plot(kind='bar')

# Set the facecolor
ax.set_facecolor('black')

# Set the labelcolor
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('red')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')

# Set the legend with other facecolor
ax.legend(fontsize = 11,          
          facecolor = 'lightgray',   
          edgecolor = 'red',   
          title = 'Clients by',    
          title_fontsize = '12',          
         )

plt.title("US Clients")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete `labelcolor` parameter when initializing `fig` variable:

```
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass = Waffle, 
    rows = 4,
    columns = 8,
    values = gender,
    colors = ('#B13167', '#3274A1'),
    labels = ['{} - {}'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(gender.index, gender)],
    legend = {
        'loc': 'upper left', 
        'bbox_to_anchor': (1, 1), 
        'fontsize': 15,
        'title': 'Gender',
        'title_fontsize': 15,
        'facecolor': 'white'
        },
    font_size = 75, 
    icons = ['venus', 'mars'],
    icon_legend = True,
    figsize = (15, 8),
    facecolor = 'black'
)
```

Comment: its work now but without Graphics

Comment: I need this graph for my project . the code is working correct but the graph not appear as a resulat

Comment: @2nols The code its not supposed to plot anything, you need to add `plot()` function or similar after `plt.figure()` to plot your data

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: where I should add plot() function?

Comment: @2nols After `fig = plt.figure()`

Comment: now I have this error what dose means?

Comment: PlotlyError: Error in dataframe. Make sure all entries of each column are either numbers or strings.

Comment: can you check it from colab?

Comment: @2nols You need to convert all the values of your `dataframe` to string, or int depending on the data. If you have lists, booleans, or any other data type, it will cause an issue.